# OpenSeadragon: Using a proxy to get XML data is causing tiles not to load

Tags: c#, xml, proxy, seadragon, openseadragon

I have a site that uses OpenSeadragon to display deep zoom images. I have it working with some test images, but the images I need are on a domain that I cannot access from my webpage due to a security issue (No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header). For the record, the page hosting the DZI images is owned by my company, but because it is an Amazon S3 site, I am unable to add the header to the site because Amazon does not provide that capability.

I've created a Proxy controller, and the controller successfully gets the XML data it needs. Here is my controller code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string bucket, string guid)
    {
        guid = guid.ToLower(); // in case guid is passed as uppercase
        string url = "http://" + bucket + ".img.mywebsite.org/" + guid +  ".xml";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string serverData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(serverData);
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        // create new XML doc
        // load serverData into XML doc
        // return XMLdoc

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(serverData)
        };
    }
```

The controller returns the XML data correctly. For example, when I go to http://mysite.mvc/api/test?bucket=66&guid=e41de95d-6235-4581-b823-4887b50eb8ad, I get a page with correct looking XML data. I have also tested this on the DHC chrome extension.

On my webpage, I make an Ajax call to the proxy controller, and use the returned XML to open Seadragon:

```
        var imgdata = {
            bucket: "66",
            guid: "e41de95d-6235-4581-b823-4887b50eb8ad",
        };

        var ajaxresult = $.ajax({
            url: "/api/test",
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                //alert("Success");
                alert(data);
                var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
                    id: "viewerdiv",
                    prefixUrl: "../../Scripts/openseadragon/images/",
                    tileSources: data 
                });

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
            },
            data: imgdata
        });
        console.log(ajaxresult);
```

The alert in my Ajax success function displays the XML I expect. However, in my Seadragon viewer, the tiles do not display (but the viewer is open, and the nav buttons are there). In my console, I have this response:

```
Tile a.Tile failed to load: 10/01.jpg
```

for every tile in the image. I suspect this is because my Seadragon viewer is being opened with static XML that is not actually linked to the webpage where it is from, but I have no idea what to do about this. Is there something I can do to fix it, or is my Proxy controller simply not going to work? And if it doesn't work, what else can I do to display these images?

edit: another thought I have is that maybe the tilesources aren't loading because the data is being passed in as a string and not as an XML document?

I also tried this instead of OpenSeadragon()

```
var viewer = new Seadragon.Viewer("familysearch");
viewer.openDzi(data);
```

but got a 400 bad request error in my Seadragon viewer.

I also tried slicing off the heading of the XML by using data.substring(38), but same error. My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Image TileSize="256" Overlap="1" Format="jpg" ServerFormat="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2009">
        <Size Width="550" Height="1765" />
    </Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OpenSeadragon does not yet support passing the XML directly; you'll have to break apart the info. See the answer here:

https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/460